# How can I enable source file dropping in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi, editor

The earlier IDEs (10.2) enable to drag and drop source files from external apps (for example Total Commander) to open them.
But Delphi 10.3 does not enable it with default settings. The mouse cursor is a slashed circle. Is there any way to make this useful feature alive again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is as uncovered in the comments. Drag and drop support works just as it always did. The problem is that you run the IDE elevated. The operating system blocks drag and drop operations to processes with higher integrity levels than the drag source. So the behaviour is as expected.

The solution is to run the IDE as standard user.

Comment: Yes. This is my dream, but the registration help me to keep dreaming about it.